# split the array in powershell while inserting record into database

Tags: powershell

I am writing powershell script to read the SQL instance name on list of database servers.

I have doubled so far is this.

1. Reading the servers names from SQL database by making a connection.
2. Read the registry key value on the server and return instance names.
3. Insert the result back to table with servername vs instance name (**Each server might have more than one instance **)

My script is working as expected when there is only 1 instance name but where is there are more than 1 instance return from the registry, my variable is inserting hole array into table as a single value.

My result is looking like below which i don't want

---

```
SVC_Server SVC_Instnace
Server1    MSSQLSERVER
Server2    MSSQLSERVER INST1
Server3    MSSQLSERVER INST1 INST2
```

---

I was expecting the result like this

---

```
SVC_Server SVC_Instnace
Server1    MSSQLSERVER
Server1    INST1
Server2    MSSQLSERVER
Server2    INST1
Server3    MSSQLSERVER
Server3    INST1 
Server3    INST2
```

---

I tried following methods to handle but no luck.

1. Created foreach loop : This will read server name that qualified in try block
2. For-each qualified server do a for loop execution against the length of instances
3. Tried using split but no luck.

Its my learning stage in powershell..I would appreciate your help.

```
$Tsql = "SELECT svr_name  FROM server"
    $ServerList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Tsql -ServerInstance $sql_inst -Database $sql_db 
    $Servers = $ServerList.Svr_name   
  # ECHO $Servers
 foreach($Server in $Servers)

 {
 try 
 {

  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Localmachine', $Server)
  $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server" )

  If ($regKey.GetSubKeyNames() -contains 'Instance Names' -or $regKey.GetValueNames() -contains 'InstalledInstances' ) 
     {
   $instances = $regKey.GetValue('InstalledInstances')
   #ECHO $instances
     } 
  ElseIf ($regKey.GetValueNames() -contains 'Instance Names') 
   {


   $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Instance Names\\SQL" ) 
     $instances = @($regkey.GetValueNames())
   } 

 foreach($Srv in $Server)
  {

  if ($instances.count -gt 1) {
      for($i=0; $i -ge $instances.Length ;$i++)
         {
           Invoke-SQLCMD -Query "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SVC_Instance] ([SVC_Server],[SVC_Instance]) VALUES  ( ('$Server'),('$instances[i]')) " -Database $sql_db -ServerInstance $sql_inst
           ECHO  $Server
           ECHO $instances
          }

       }
  else 
  {   
  Invoke-SQLCMD -Query "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SVC_Instance] ([SVC_Server],[SVC_Instance]) VALUES  ( ('$Server'),('$instances')) " -Database $sql_db -ServerInstance $sql_inst }
  ECHO 'Else is executed'
  }
  #ECHO $Server 
  #ECHO $instances

  }

 Catch
  {

  "Something wrong with  : $Server " | Out-file 'C:\ServerPatching\Failed_Servers.txt' -Append
   #ECHO $Server 
  }
  # ECHO $instances




   }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach($Srv in $Server)
{

#### Finally its worked for me as shown below. Thanks

```
      foreach($inst in $instances)

      { 
      Invoke-SQLCMD -Query "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SVC_Instance] ([SVC_Server],[SVC_Instance]) VALUES  ( ('$Server'),('$inst')) " -Database $sql_db -ServerInstance $sql_inst
      
      
       }
```